# create symlink to thunderbolt external drive

Tags: symlink

Can someone please help me create a symlink on my Mac to my external NAS via thunderbolt:

The source location of the folder is:

smb://169.254.8.133/MEDIA/Music/REKORDBOX

and the where i would like the symlink to be placed is:

/Users/X/Music

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Is there a special reason that the usual command in Terminal doesn‘t work for you?